# python selenium excpected conditions send_keys

Tags: python, selenium

i'm having a problem with the following code:

```
iFrame = EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(("MAIN_IFRAME"))
uscita = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(.,'password')]"))
uscita.send_keys('passwd')
```

and i'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'presence_of_element_located' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

i'm new Python's user and I would like your help on this problem.

Thanks

HTML for iframe and input:

```
<td style="text-align:center">
    <iframe height="350" width="450" name="timb" src="timb.php" style="position: relative;top:0px"></iframe>
</td>
<td>
    <div style="position: relative;top:0px">

        <form action="mnghlog6.php" method="post" target="timbri">
            <input type="hidden" id="esculappio" name="escu" value="0">
            <table style="position: relative;top:0px">
            </div></td><td><div class="buttons" style="display:inline;text-align: left;">
            </div></td></tr><tr><td><div class="buttons" style="display:inline;text-align: left;">
            </div></td><td><div class="buttons" style="display:inline;text-align: left;">
            </div></td></tr></tbody></table>                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center">Password <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="30" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="flag_inizio">
            <input type="hidden" name="durata">
        </form>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html
`presence_of_element_located` returns you `explicit wait` that you need to resolve to use waiting element.

Comment: Could you share your HTML for frame and input as well.??

Comment: I've omitted some code from the html because wasn't accepted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `until` function from `WebDriverWait` with the `expected_conditions`. It also doesn't looks like the field is in `iframe`. Try this

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
uscita = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password")))
uscita.send_keys('passwd')
```

By the way, to switch to the frame you can do something like

```
iFrame = wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "timb")))
```

Comment: I get a TimeoutException when I try this.

Comment: @ErjolBane where? also, please add the relevant html.

Comment: @ErjolBane `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` should get locator. not string, just like `presence_of_element_located`

Comment: the error is at the iframe line. and the html code is "  <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center">Password <input name="password" id="password" size="30" value="" type="password"></td>
            </tr>"

Comment: though looking more carefully at the html code I'm noticing that the above html code is inside another iframe that I'm not managing to locate.

Comment: @ErjolBane what is the html for that `iframe`?

Comment: I had to ".switch_to.default_content()" to select the other frame. now it works